# Typeahead: Adding a last option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using Bootstrap v2.3.2 and I have a regular typeahead set up that gets data from a database.

I'm trying to make it so that the last result of each typeahead is the option "Search for <what you typed>". So if you typed "hello" in the input, the last option (under all other results) would be `Search for "hello"`.

How would this be done?

Comment: can you share your typeahead code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the source parameter of Typeahead.

Here is how I implemented the same thing in my website :-

```
    $("#typeahead").typeahead({
        'source'=>function(query, process){
            return $.get("URL_OF_SEARCH", {string:query}, function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data); 
                var list = $.map(data, function(item){
                     var aItem = {
                         id: item.id, name: item.text, picture: item.picture
                     }; 
                     return JSON.stringify(aItem);
                }); 
                //Till here everything was done to fetch previous results and show them
                list.push({"id":"URL_OF_SEARCH/" + query ,"name":"Search for "+query, "picture":"/favicon.ico"}); 
                //This above line adds the last row which you want to add
                return process(list);
             });
        },
        'highlighter'=>function(item){
            item = JSON.parse(item);
            var itm = "<div class='typeahead_wrapper'>"
            + "<img class='typeahead_photo' src='" + item.picture + "'/>"
            + "<div class='typeahead_labels'>"
            + "<div class='typeahead_primary'>" + item.name + "</div></div></div>";
            return itm;
        },
     });
```

I used 3 things to show in the list, a picture, a name and a link(ID). To implement this I also had to modify my highlighter function.

I hope this helps you.